# How to fix shell prompt ( ps1 ) odd escape sequences after remote login from iTerm2

Tags: linux, terminal, prompt, gnome-terminal

I am observing the below strange prompt after login to my remote machine from  ubuntu 14.04. This only happens while I'm using the ubuntu gui terminal and not via putty. Any suggestion to fix it?

[image: This is the output after login to the remote server.]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your `~/.bashrc` [file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77845/my-terminal-prompt-ps1-mixed-up) Also, what happens when you do `PS1='$ '` for instance?

Comment: What OS is your remote machine? What shell does it use? What is the value of $PS1 on the remote side?

Comment: @michas remote machine is centos release 5.4 (Final), it uses /bin/bash , value of $PS1 , ` [deploy@admin:~]$ ]133;Becho $PS1
]133;C;[\[\033[01;33m\]\u\[\033[01;37m\]@\[\033[00;32m\]admin\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]]$
]133;D;0]1337;RemoteHost=deploy@ip-10-165-35-177]1337;CurrentDir=/home/deploy]133;A[deploy@admin:~]$ ]133;B `code`

Comment: Does `reset` do anything useful?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov no use. still same prompt

Comment: please do not add output into comments. it's really hard to read and hides important information. Please edit your question and add this kind of information directly there.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed iTerm2 integration.  Rather than removing it, test dynamically for iTerm2 should have done inside their integration script. **Note: See warning about ssh below.**

There is an ANSI sequence that iterm will respond to which works regardless of what shell/ssh is active. For people wanting to roll their own the sequence is **`printf '\x1b[1337n'`**.

Your .bashrc (or whatever shell init you use) probably has something like:

> test -r ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash && . ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash

Possibly without the initial test.  Just change it to an even uglier:

> **[isiterm2.sh](https://iterm2.com/utilities/it2check) &&** test -r ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash && . ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash

**VS Code Remote Explorer/SSH Users**  VS code seems to auto-type/feed characters to the ssh connection when starting up.  Those commands can get chopped off by the stty reset sequence in isIterm2.sh. My short term hack has been to do this check/load on the 2nd display of the prompt. This is *such* a kludge though.

Comment: not work for me: my ssh client shell is Ubuntu 16.04 default shell.

Comment: I've edited with a more complete solution.

Comment: New tool change from `isiterm2.sh` to https://iterm2.com/utilities/it2check

Answer (score 3):

The strings aren't actually *ANSI sequences*.  Rather, they started as ANSI sequences, but are translated (due to some scripting error) on your remote machine so that most of the characters are converted to a different form.

An *ANSI sequence* for instance would have

<kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

possibly with an optional <kbd>;</kbd> before the <kbd>A</kbd>, but the problematic output shows a `133` (<kbd>[</kbd> is octal 133).  Likewise, the screenshot shows a literal `\033` rather than the ASCII escape character, in several places.

Very likely the difference between the gui terminal and putty is that the former may have `TERM` set to `xterm-256color`, while PuTTY has its own configuration, and `TERM` was not set in PuTTY (and its default is `xterm`).

Ubuntu 14.04 didn't do this by itself (it's been around a while, and no one's complained about *this*), so it's a post-install "improvement".  As suggested, start by looking in your own `.bashrc` (or color-theme scripts that you added - some of those are very buggy).

Comment: (1) I agree with you about the `133`s being suspicious. (2) Note that all the backslashes occur on the line after a line that ends with `echo $PS1`, and that line looks like a valid (raw) PS1 value, with ``\[\033[…m\]``, ``\u``, and ``\w`` — and it corresponds to part of the prompt that the OP is getting. I guess the OP typed `echo $PS1` and didn’t mention it. (3) Every occurrence of `133` is immediately preceded by a character that is a rectangle containing `001B` — and of course Escape is hex 1B. This seems to confirm your conclusion that `▯133` sequences are corrupted (Escape)`[` sequences.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like iTerm2's shell integration. See http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html.

Check to see if .iterm2_shell_integration.bash is being sourced by .bash_profile.

Comment: iTerm2 is MacOS - the OP is running Ubuntu locally and CentOS remotely.

Comment: Yes but .iterm2_shell_integration.bash does not know or care what OS you are running. I just had this problem logging into Ubuntu from Mint, because someone (who uses OSX and iTerm2) added the script to the Ubuntu server.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me, and removing .iterm2_shell_integration.bash did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This data very much looks like [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Those can be used to switch color of your characters, to change the title bar of your terminal emulator and much more.

They work by printing those codes directly to screen and hoping that your terminal emulator understands them correctly.

Some (like changing color) are implemented in pretty much every terminal emulator. Some more exotic might be implemented in only some emulators and some might be only made for one particular terminal emulator. (like putty)

If you terminal emulator does not recognize the codes it ignores them and simply prints "garbage" on screen.

In your case someone might have added putty-specific codes. It's currently hard to read, what exactly is the content in your case.

Have a look in `~/.bashrc`. Most likely your PS1 prompt is defined there. It might give you a hint, what its intend is.

If you just want to get rid of it, simply set your own PS1 prompt and everything should be good.

Comment: No.way. around. i check my bashrc with default of other use bashrc. there were no changes around. While trying to change the PS1 in local and remote also gives same values. i assume this was only the gnome way of interpreting these as strings. i tried all way to change colors but dont know exactly which was causing this extra bits.

Answer (score 0):

This is becasue of the non-standard escape codes of Iterm2s: [Proprietary Escape Codes](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html), which has been issued here: [Shell integration displays invalid characters on Linux terminals](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5372#). To fix this problem, execute these commands in your remote server which has installed iTerm2 integration:

1. `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/isiterm2.sh > ~/.isiterm2.sh && chmod ug+x ~/.isiterm2.sh`
2. Modify your `.bash_profile` (or `.profile` or wherever) to condition loading shell integration on that script succeeding:

   `~/.isiterm2.sh  &&  test -e "$HOME/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"  &&  source "$HOME/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"`